# Where to store model-related repetitive code in Djangо?

Tags: django, django-models, architecture

I'm looking for a proper way to manage repetitive model-related code in Django that does not belong to the model logic.

Keep in mind that:

1. "Comments" is a reusable app, that can be used in other projects
2. "Comments" example it's just an illustration of the problem

**Example:**

```
class Comments(models.model):
    ### model stuff ###
```

Threaded comments rendering is an expensive operation, so I want to store them into the cache as HTML.

Repetitive code that we have to deal with:

```
def get_comments_html(target_object):
    ## check cache
    ## is there is no cached copy, then build HTML and store to the cache
```

I think that Comments model caching logic doesn't relate to the Comments itself and should be placed anywhere else.

**Ways to solve the problem:**

Here are three approaches I see to solve this problem:

1. Store **ALL** such functionality into model consumer class:

   ```
   class ModelConsumer(object):
       # here we can place repetitive code for all models (of just pass)

   class CommentsConsumer(ModelConsumer):
       model = Comments

       def get_comments_html(self, target_object): 
           # check for cahce
           comments = self.model.object.filter(target=target_object)
           # render HTML and store to cache
   ```
2. Store such logic independently as plain functions in comment_app/utils.py
3. Create independent class for each problem (f.e. CommentCacheManager and so on)

**What is the best solution to deal with model-related code that does not belong to the model logic?**

*This question is devoted to finding an architectural concept that will not result in product limitations in the future.*

Comment: As I understand it, the goal is to cache HTML, because it's rendering is expensive. Is there a reason why you don't use Django's template cache? Is the caching logic to complex to achieve with template caching? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching

Comment: @Max, no. You misunderstood me. Comments are just an illustration of the problem. The question is in finding the best way of dealing with all variety of such problems. When we have model-related code that doesn't belong to model logic.

Answer (score 0):

If the repetitive code is only for caching HTML fragments, you might go for [Django's template caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching).

However, there might be trouble if the caching logic is not trivial. `get_comments_html` seems to always operate on a QuerySet of comments. Instead of placing this code in a manager, you could add a [custom QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods) to the model which allows you to use the cache-logic like this:

```
comments_html = Comment.objects.filter(target=target_object).get_comments_html()
```

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to put caching into QuerySet? Keep in mind that "comments" is a reusable app, that can be used in other projects.